# Where to find 1900 Swiss census for Bern?

Tags: 20th-century, census-records, switzerland

I have a birth certificate for my grandfather Ernst Bachmann. He was born in Bern, Switzerland in 1903.

I doesn't have very much information on it. It has his father's name but not his mothers name. It has a female name on it Rosette born Bachman. I was originally guessing it is a sibling or maybe even a twin. But I've also been told by an aunt that Rosette was born Bachmann and also Married a Bachmann, so probably not a sibling.

I'm looking for a swiss census to help fill in the blanks.

Can someone direct me to the right place to search for this census?

[image]
It is a civil birth certificate with the seal of Bern on it

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user I recommend taking the 2-minute  [Tour].  I've not looked for a Swiss Census before and can see that your question would not be answered by visiting the [FamilySearch Wiki](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Switzerland_Census).  While you await an answer you may want to review [our earlier Q&As related to Switzerland](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/switzerland).

Comment: Is this certificate from a civil registration or is it a church record? Before searching for a census, it might help to find out more information you have about the document you already have.  You may use the 'edit' link under your question to add any new information to your question.

Comment: @Vernpaw Bachman - Was your grandfather born in the city of Bern or the canton of Bern? What is the name of the field that includes the female name? (An image of the certificate would help us better interpret the information you have).

Answer (score 3):

I think you have asked for access to the Swiss census, expecting that you would see household information like the U.S. 1900 census. However, although the Swiss censuses were taken every 10 years and there was a 1900 Swiss census, the only published information is statistical (see [Swiss Statistics](http://www.bfs.admin.ch/bfs/portal/en/index/150.html)). This information is available for purchase, but is unlikely to contain any names. The raw data may be archived somewhere, but I found no indications that access is allowed.

Other references

- [Census in Switzerland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Census_in_Switzerland)
- [Federal Statistical Office (Switzerland)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Statistical_Office_(Switzerland))

A better approach would be to pursue family records through the placenames on the birth certificate. It was issued in Schwartzenegg, Kanton Bern (not the city of Bern). The child Ernst was born in Unterlangenegg and father Christian Bachmann was from Buchholterberg and living in Unterlangenegg. Origin of mother (Rosette nee Bachmann) not given. These placenames are the key to finding more about your ancestors (see the answers to the other Swiss questions).